# Codeigniter / linux / mssql 2005 - no local chars (diarcritic marks)

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord, character-encoding, collation

I'm having a problem setting up codeigniter connection to mssql 2005 database on the linux. I managed to establish connection, but the data returned/parsed by the Codeigniter functions is missing all diacritic marks like [ąężźćäöüß]. In firebug they are replaced with questionmarks within the rectangle, in notepad with black diamonds. Example:

```
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => *
            [zid] => *
            [keyid] => AEDF
            [status] => A
            [txt] => 20.000, je�eli > 50 lat + 15 lat sta�u
        )
```

I played a lot with the configuration.

```
$db['loga']['hostname'] = '10.0.0.90:4113';
$db['loga']['username'] = 'user';
$db['loga']['password'] = 'password';
$db['loga']['database'] = 'TESTDB';
$db['loga']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['loga']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['loga']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['loga']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['loga']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['loga']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['loga']['char_set'] = 'utf-8';
$db['loga']['dbcollat'] = 'Polish_CI_AS';
$db['loga']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['loga']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['loga']['stricton'] = FALSE;

/* End of file database.php */
```

The database collation is set to Polish_CI_AS - and cannot be changed (cp1250). I'm already confused how to interpret all of the parameters in CI database config file. I assumed $db['loga']['dbcollat'] represents database collation, where char_set is... i don't know anymore :)

In the end I expect data to be in UTF-8 ( so they could be properly displayed in the browser ).

I also did my homework and tried using:
@ini_set('mssql.charset', 'utf-8');

which didn't work for me - No visible impact on the results. I also tried to mess with freeTDS config file ( setting 'client charset = UTF-8' ) - still no results.

It's worth to mention, that I know only basics of linux OS, so I might have missed somethig. I have found in php.ini file that mssql.charset param works only as intended if the php was compiled with freeTDS. I can only assume that it is the case.

Anyways, I have no problem with the script while running it on the Windows Server ( and using sqlsrv driver ).

Any suggestions where to find solution? What don't I understand or understand not correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/freetds/freetds.conf on Ubuntu , I add those two lines and reload Apache.

```
[global]
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

It works for me.